# Sharing and publishing a google doc ends up in similar, guessable urls

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

According to google documentation ([here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en-GB&rd=1) and [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/learningcenter/Google-Docs-Sheets-and-Slides-Share-and-collaborate.pdf) for example), users should be able to create a private url to share the document, e.g. with edit privileges for collegues and, at the same time, publish the document for the public with an other url ("[...] In other words, by publishing Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides, you’re creating a copy of them that’s a unique webpage with its own public URL.").

However when a file is shared with the Share menu and then it is published with File -> Publish, the two generated urls are very similar, e.g.:

- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oO1-WIwCI7qA2AqAO2LxHN_ZMYM8wiz8XoY9Xwf3ogY/edit?usp=sharing
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oO1-WIwCI7qA2AqAO2LxHN_ZMYM8wiz8XoY9Xwf3ogY/pub

Obviously whoever has the public url can guess the private one as well. So either the documentation is not clear on this aspect, or there is a bug in the sharing functionality (or yes, it's me that I didn't get something very simple, it can be, it's Friday afternoon..)

Answer (score 0):

everything seems ok to me. so lets assume someone with the public url guesses the private url. so what? the would still need to have the document shared with them to view/edit.

have a good weekend.

Comment: hi, not necessary.. my configuration is to have an edit-link, meaning that everyone with such link can edit.. that's the purpose of creating the edit-link: I don't need to know who is member of my organisation to share the doc with him, I can just send it to the internal mailing list.. obviously we are not speaking of critical docs..

Comment: to avoid your issue with sharing links, instead share with the entire organization instead of by link.

Comment: How do I share a document with an organisation? Any how, I can find workaround (e.g. made copies for the "public version" time to time), but still it remains that the documentation is misleading, letting you believe that the share by link and publish links result in different urls...